# Notation of a volume integral

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

I see a physics textbook that switches between the following three notations:

\begin{equation}
    \int_V \text{d}V
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \int_V \text{d}^3\vec x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \int_V \text{d}^3 x
\end{equation}

where all three are meant to be equivalent. The quantity $V$ is the volume of a sphere and $\vec x$ is a position vector.

The latter two seem to be in contradiction. Which is correct? Or are all three fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not contradictory, it is just a notation to denote a volume element, just keep that in mind, here are some other notations I've seen around

- $\displaystyle{\iiint_V {\rm d}^{3}V}$
- $\displaystyle{\iiint_V {\rm d}x{\rm d}y{\rm d}z}$
- $\displaystyle{\int_V {\rm d}^3{\bf r}}$

As long as you are clear on the meaning of all these symbols: volume integral over the region $V$, there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: What about the difference between $\int_V \text{d}^3 \mathbf{r}$ and $\int_V \text{d}^3 r$? Did the author simply forget to bold the r?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron Could be, or also could be the way they call the volume element, the point is that if you agree that this is a volume element, then there's no problem at all

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned that you were reading a physics book, I suppose there are at least three aspects involved.

**Firstly**, physicists usually state the laws of physics first before worrying about computation. Laws of physics are valid for the space in which phenomena occur. A standard model for this space is Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^N$. In order to compute, you have to use a chart $C \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with coordinates.
$\mathbb{R}^N$ is a particular Euclidean space in which computations can be performed because points are labelled by numbers.

A typical example is the balance of mass. A physicist might express in a math-like notation,  that conservation of mass is assumed by writing
$$ 
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \int \limits_{\mathcal{B} }\bar{\rho} \mathrm{d} V \,= 0 .
$$
Even what looks like a "time derivative" is at this point only a declaration of interest called the material "time derivative".

For computation, you have to use a chart and then you may write down in coordinates how to compute the mass of the object, e.g.,
$$
M= \int \int \int_\Omega \rho(x_1, x_2, x_3) \, \mathrm{d} x_1 \mathrm{d} x_2 \mathrm{d} x_3 \, .
$$
using a particular chart with coordinates $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$.

**Secondly**, as already pointed out by *caverac*, different notations are possible and notation is eventually also a matter of taste. But, notation matters a lot because it determines how much time is needed to understand a problem. Therefore, regarding $\mathbb{R}^N$, I think
$$
\int_\Omega \rho \, \mathrm{d}^N  \, x
$$
is a good choice because it is short, flexible and not ambiguous:

- you know from $N$, that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and,
- obviously, you need coordinates $x_i, i=1,..N$.

**Thirdly**, if, for instance, integration theorems are involved, many people prefer a notation like
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \vec{u} \,  \mathrm{d} V
= \int_{\partial \Omega} \, \vec{u} \cdot \vec{n} \, \mathrm{d} S
$$
in order to avoid a discussion about the technicalities of integration over nonlinear surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ at a point where it only might distract the reader from what authors consider important at this moment.

Comment: Please focus on newer answers, rather than expand on already existing answers posted almost five years ago.